# rest_framework NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_tasks.assigner_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, notnull

I am making an app where assigner can assign tasks to assignee 
when i run the server and try to add a task i get this error:

NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks_tasks.assigner_id

here is my views:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import Tasks
from .serializers import TasksSerializer, UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tasks.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TasksSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def prefrom_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(self, assigner=self.request.user)
```

here is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Tasks
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class TasksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assigner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='assigner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'title', 'description', 'assigner', 'assignee')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(many=True, view_name='tasks_details', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'username', 'tasks')
```

and finally my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Tasks(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    assigner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='tasks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='assigned', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made `assigner` a read only field with source `assigner.username` -this is your problem. I think you could get around this by defining two fields instead, one read_only and one write_only:

```
class TasksSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
assigner_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='assigner.username')
assigner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, queryset=User.objects.all(), required=True)
class Meta:
    model = Tasks
    fields = ('id', 'url', 'title', 'description', 'assigner', 'assignee', 'assigner_name')
```

The effect of this code is that when your serializer is 'writing' (de-serializing) it will accept the assigner id which you pass into the save method as the keyword argument `assigner`. When it then serializes the task to json, it will look for the `assigner.name` and return it under the key `assigner_name` and miss out `assigner`.

In the view, you'd then pass in the primary key (rather than the whole object) to the serializer save method:

```
serializer.save(assigner=self.request.user.pk)
```

Comment: in rest_frame work tutorial it was done like that, i did ur suggestion, but now i get another problem that u have to choose the assigner and it's not automatically declared. but the problem is solved anyway and i can now add tasks

Comment: it's not automatically what?

Comment: is there a way to solve it without making the user able to choose the assigner and assign it automatically to the user of the current session?

Comment: Just to check, is the typo in `perform_create` also in your code? You've written it as `preform` rather than `perform`. I think this might actually have been your original problem - you can go back to your previous implementation and just correct this typo and it will work fine

Comment: nope, i write it perform in the code and still the same problem